# Photostripe with background color that spans over whole pagewidth?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, color, backgrounds, tabu

For a poster, I need to get three photos in a stripe (3x1 grid layout). Also, the stripe should be colored ir order to fill the whitespace between the photos (and the adjacent margins).

My first approach was with `\centerline`, `tabu` and `colortbl` package, but I can't get the photos aligned properly to the margins *and* have them colored.
Secondly, I tried a simple `tikzpicture` which has some superfluous spacings (both vertically and horizontally) I need to get rid of.

Therefore, I have created the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=12.7mm, right=12.7mm, top=12.7mm, bottom=13mm]{geometry}
\parindent0mm
\usepackage{showframe, mwe}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, shapes, backgrounds}
\newlength\pictureheight
\setlength{\pictureheight}{30mm}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[2]
\medskip
%% Fotostreifen mit tabu
\centerline
{
\tabulinesep^0.1pt_0pt
\begin{tabu}to \textwidth[c]{@{}X[l,m,2] X[c,m,1.5] X[r,m,2] @{}}
\rowcolor{blue}
\includegraphics[height=\pictureheight]{example-image-16x9} &
\includegraphics[height=\pictureheight]{example-image-16x10} &
\includegraphics[height=\pictureheight]{example-image-16x9}
\\
\end{tabu}
}

\medskip
\lipsum[2]

\centerline
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0mm and 0mm, show background rectangle, 
  background rectangle/.style={fill=blue}, anchor=center]
\node(lRand) at (0,1)[shape=rectangle, color=blue]{};
\node(bild1) at (1.27,0)[anchor=south west]
{\includegraphics[height=\pictureheight]{example-image-16x9}};
\node(bild2) at (10.5,0)[anchor=south]
{\includegraphics[height=\pictureheight]{example-image-16x10}};
\node(bild3) at (19.73,0)[anchor=south east]
{\includegraphics[height=\pictureheight]{example-image-16x9}};
\node(rRand) at (21,1)[shape=rectangle, color=blue]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\medskip
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

And this is how it looks like:
[image: photostripeBackgroundColor]

I want to get the images arranged like in the first example (using `tabu`) with the color vertically cropped, but with the background color box spanning over the whole pagewidth like in the second example (using `TikZ`).
Any ideas?

Comment: It would be easier if you apply the first method and then *extend* the background using `\tikzmark`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two other ways to do it.  The first puts the entire `tabu` inside a node, and the second uses `tikzpagenodes` to place each image relative to the `(current page text area)` node.

Note: it take two runs for `[remember picture]` to work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=12.7mm, right=12.7mm, top=12.7mm, bottom=13mm]{geometry}
\parindent0mm
\usepackage{showframe, mwe}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, shapes, backgrounds}
\newlength\pictureheight
\setlength{\pictureheight}{30mm}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[2]
\medskip
%% Fotostreifen mit tikz

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=5pt] (A)% outer sep conmtrols top/bottom margin
{\parbox{\textwidth}{% not sure why this is needed
  \tabulinesep^0.1pt_0pt
  \begin{tabu}to \textwidth[c]{@{}X[l,m,2] X[c,m,1.5] X[r,m,2] @{}}
  \includegraphics[height=\pictureheight]{example-image-16x9} &
  \includegraphics[height=\pictureheight]{example-image-16x10} &
  \includegraphics[height=\pictureheight]{example-image-16x9}
  \\
  \end{tabu}}%
};
\path (A.south) -- (A.north);% reserve space for overlay
\begin{scope}[on background layer, overlay]
  \fill[blue] (A.south-|current page.west) rectangle (A.north-|current page.east); 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip
\lipsum[2]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\node[right, inner sep=0pt] at (origin-|current page text area.west)
  {\includegraphics[height=\pictureheight]{example-image-16x9}};
\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=5pt] (A) at (origin-|current page text area.center)
  {\includegraphics[height=\pictureheight]{example-image-16x10}};
\node[left, inner sep=0pt] at (origin-|current page text area.east)
  {\includegraphics[height=\pictureheight]{example-image-16x9}};
\path (A.south) -- (A.north);% reserve space for overlay
\begin{scope}[on background layer, overlay]
  \fill[blue] (A.south-|current page.west) rectangle (A.north-|current page.east); 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Both soultions work, but they both have the blue margin above&beyond, which I need to get rid of. I know that I could generate the photo stripe in a separate file, then use `\includegraphics` with `trim` and `clip` option, but there should be a better way. Is it just some `inner sep=0pt` stuff?

Comment: Nevermind, I've realized that you already mentioned this in your source-code comment. So with `outer sep=0pt`, I get *exactly* what I want! And it's quite elegantly coded.
I've also found that with `current page text area` instead of `current page`, I can eclipse the blue margins, which is convenient if the printer is uncapable of marginless plotting. Thanks a lot!